# fetchOne in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In Zend, I usually use fetchOne to recept my result when I have only one result (string or int) from my query.

For example :

My model (Zend) :

```
$query = "
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user
";

return $this->getAdapter()->fetchOne($query, null, Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
```

and in my controler (Zend) :

```
$table = new Application_Model_TUser;
$number = $table->nUser();
echo $number; // return 5
```

I would like to do the same thing into CodeIgniter... It's possible ? or am i forced to do :

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Nb FROM user")->row()->Nb;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
return $this->db->count_all('user'); // returns int
```

Or if you want to add conditions use:

```
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->where($conditions);
return $this->db->count_all_results(); // returns int
```

**Update:** Based on your comment, it would be best to get it like your have written in your question:

```
return $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Nb FROM user")->row()->Nb;
```

Or without using `query()`, in more of an "active record" fashion:

```
$where = array('userID'=>'1');
$query = $this->db->get_where('user', $where);
$row = $query->row();
return $row->name;
```

Comment: It's not only to do COUNT(*), i would like to extract one column like : SELECT name FROM user WHERE userID = 1